# Eclipse Scout - Clean Database authentication

Tags: java, eclipse-scout

I'm trying to implement a database authentication with Eclipse Scout.

For that I created a class `DataSourceCredentialVerifier` in the *client* module, which implements the `ICredentialVerifier`interface. Then I adapted the `init` method of the `UiServletFilter` class to use my verifier.

```
public class DataSourceCredentialVerifier implements ICredentialVerifier {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceCredentialVerifier.class);

@Override
public int verify(String username, char[] password) throws IOException {
    Object queryResult[][] = BEANS.get(IMySqlAuthService.class).load();


    return AUTH_OK;
}
```

I haven't implemented any authentication logic yet. My task now is to establish a clean database connection.

For that I created the following `interface`  in the *shared* module:

```
public interface IMySqlAuthService extends IService {

    Object[][] load();
}
```

The implementation is in the *server* module:

```
   public class MySqlAuthService implements IMySqlAuthService {

        @Override
        public Object[][] load() {
            String sql = "select username, password from users ";
            Object[][] queryResult = SQL.select(sql, null, null);       
            return queryResult;
        }
   }
```

First I want to see, if there is at least something in the query, but I get an AssertionException here:

```
 Object queryResult[][] = BEANS.get(IMySqlAuthService.class).load();

org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.util.Assertions$AssertionException: Assertion error: no instance found for query: interface org.eclipse.scout.app.shared.services.IMySqlAuthService
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.util.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:580)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.util.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:87)
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.BEANS.get(BEANS.java:41)
```

I don't get an instance of my `MySqlAuthService` implementation. I assume that the `BeanManager` should have created an instance for me. `MySqlAuthService` should be registered as a Bean, since my `IMySqlAuthService` interface extends from `IService` which has the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation.

Adding the `@Bean` annotation to `MySqlAuthService` results in the same exception.

Here some information about the `BeanManager` and annotations: 
https://eclipsescout.github.io/6.0/technical-guide.html#sec-bean.manager

Here is another different approach s.o. tried, but it doesn't feel correct:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1079741/

How can I get my example to work with my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution with important explanations of Eclipse Scout principles.

The source is summarized information of the Eclipse-Scout-Technical-Guide.

In Scout there is a built in annotation: `@TunnelToServer`. Interfaces marked with this annotation are called on the server. The server itself ignores this annotation. 
To achieve that a bean is registered on client side, this annotation is required. The platform **cannot** (!) directly create an instance for these beans, a specific producer is registered which creates a proxy that delegates the call to the server.

My first clear mistake was that I hadn't annotated the `IMySqlAuthService`with  `@TunnelToServer`.

After this addition I got rid of the no instance `AssertionError`.

After that my code ran into the HTTP status-code: 403 access forbidden.

This occured because my code didn't run in the correct Thread. That is the current `RunContext`. I had to use this lines of code in my `verify` method of the `DataSourceCredentialVerifier`:

```
     Subject subject = new Subject();
     subject.getPrincipals().add(new SimplePrincipal("system"));
     subject.setReadOnly();
     RunContext runContext = RunContexts.copyCurrent().withSubject(subject);
```

Now one can use the runContext's `call()` or `run()` method, depending whether the code returns a result. The action is run in the **current** thread, meaning that the caller is blocked until completion.

Concrete example solution:

```
Object[][] result = runContext.call(new Callable<Object[][]>() {

   @Override
   public Object[][] call() throws Exception {
      return BEANS.get(IMySqlAuthService.class).load();
   }

});

//TODO implement authentication logic.
```

For more information about the `RunContext` see here: 
https://eclipsescout.github.io/6.0/technical-guide.html#runcontext